# How to remove bottom zoom bar on highcharts?

Tags: highcharts

How to remove this hightlighted area in highcharts?
please share your answers. thanks
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is done by disabling the `navigator`. See [`enabled`](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#navigator.enabled). Simple example:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        navigator: {
            enabled: false
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'USD to EUR',
            data: usdeur
        }]
    });
});
```